# Do I need to show 3rd-Library-Licenses in the App I publish in Play-Store?

Tags: android, google-play

I'm using Libraries like GSON and Picasso in my App.

Do I have to copy their LICENSE and show it in my Application or on the Homepage of the App?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it concerns Google Play Store policy, rather than programming.

Comment: where should i post this question if it is on the wrong place here?

Comment: No need to show any licence for those library .you just declare them in your source code .

Comment: okey thank you! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to show LICENSE on home page of the app but specify in source code documentation for new developer understand the flow.